# Tomcat 8.5.32 returns 403 for a login request over https

Tags: tomcat, nginx, cors

I'm a little puzzled and stuck on this issue.  nginx is used as a reverse proxy and SSL terminator.  Our application server was on Tomcat 8.5.9 and everything was working as expected.  We noticed that the login requests are failing with `403` when sent over https from the client after upgrading the application server to Tomcat 8.5.32.  It appears that the requests are not even hitting our code and instead returned by tomcat with a `403` status. I don't even see any log entries in `catalina.out` or `localhost`.

After researching a bit about CORS and headers for specific request (request with Authorization data included), I figured that requests goes through if we remove `Origin` from the request.

For reference, request looks like this...

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Authorization: Basic anhjgFpbW9uLmhyg542VAa26hf5Fre76g==
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 49
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: <cookie list>
Host: myserver.mydomain.com
Origin: https://myserver.mydomain.com
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://myserver.mydomain.com/client/index.html?param=value
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.32 Safari/537.36
```

Response headers when server rejects the request.

```
Request URL: https://myserver.mydomain.com/api/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 403 
Remote Address: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Mon, 13 Aug 2018 06:16:43 GMT
Server: nginx/1.13.12
```

Login request goes through (tomcat responds with 200 for a successful login) if we remove `Origin` from request.

Appreciate some suggestions to debug this further as I'm out of ideas now. To make it clear, login goes through if I just downgrade tomcat to 8.5.9 (no other changes in reverse proxy or settings). Also login goes through if the request is sent over http instead of https.

**Update (Aug 18, 2018)**: It appears that this is caused by a [security fix](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62343) in 8.5.32.  While the request is to block request with `Origin: *`, the fix appears to be blocking any requests with `Origin` and `Credentials: true`.

Comment: It could be a web-application problem, some send a request before they login. I saw that in commercial web-apps too!

Comment: So, it seems like you've discovered what's causing the difference in behaviour.  Can you clarify whether you still require assistance?  Why not just omit the `Origin` header when making requests, as that apparently fixes the issue, per your own notes above?  TBH, I don't think it makes any sense that your request has the same hostname in both `Host` and `Origin` headers — the whole idea of CORS is cross-origin, and your scenario is same-origin.  What's causing the request to have same hostnames in both fields?

Answer (score 2):

As you've amended your question to note CVE-2018-8014, you've already figured out that the change in behaviour is due to [ASF Bug 62343](//bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62343), where prior to Tomcat 8.5.32, the default configuration of prior Tomcat may result in applications being vulnerable.

What remains unclear are the requirements that cause your request to be generated as you describe — the whole idea of CORS is enabling *cross-origin* requests, where `Host` and `Origin` HTTP Request Header Fields would describe *distinct* origins.  But in your sample request — both `Host` and `Origin` seemingly spot the same host, `myserver.mydomain.com`, which doesn't appear to make much sense.

It sounds like you might want to figure out why that's happening — if you're using the same domain, you don't need any CORS, and your request should NOT spot any `Origin` headers at all.  What software is responsible for composing the request — are you sending a manually-composed request as part of an integration test?  Then it's your test that's buggy, and is the one that must be fixed.

Otherwise, you now simply have to configure your application for appropriate CORS settings.  (The reason it worked prior to 8.5.32 was because the default settings were insecure, so, there's no mystery there.)

Another option, as a temporary fix / hack, would be to use http://nginx.org/r/proxy_hide_header and/or http://nginx.org/r/proxy_set_header (which you could use [inside of an `if`](//stackoverflow.com/a/38154810/1122270) through an intermediary variable).

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  The request is originated from the client code.  let me review the code to check if the client is adding any of `ORIGIN` or `HOST` headers.  I'm still puzzled why the request goes through over `http` and not over `https`.

Comment: @donnie, HTTP `Host` headers are added automatically through the HTTP protocol to signify the hostname, BTW; but i'd imagine that the `Origin` headers are likely self-added somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update the host name in server.xml

You need to change the name="localhost" to the value of domain configured to work with your ngnix/apache server.

```xml
<Host name="subdomain.domain.com"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" deployXML="true">
```

I have written a complete guide to add reverse proxy to tomcat with virtual host.

https://metamug.com/article/networking/lets-encrypt-ssl-on-tomcat.html